# UWP how to make Grid scrollable in XAML

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I need to make my form in XAML (in UWP app) responsive and also scrollable. I have code like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 12 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="12 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="12"/>
                    <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height" Value="auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="500"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="lblName" />
            <my:SfTextBoxExt Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="txtName" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="SecondGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="500"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="lblAge" />
            <my:SfTextBoxExt Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="txtAge" />
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

This is responsive, but not scrollable. When I add a `ScrollViewer` above the `MainGrid` -> It will be scrollable, but responsivity is not working (           `<VisualState x:Name="WideState">`)

Do you have any ides how can I make this `Grid` scrollable? Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have `VisualStateGroups` as a member of the **root** container.

The structure will be like:

```
<Grid Name=root>
    VisualStateGroups here....
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Name=MainGrid>
            ...First and Second grid...
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Putthe `VisualState` code inside `ScrollViewer` instead of `Grid`

```
 <ScrollViewer>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="24"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 12 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="12 0 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Target="FirstGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.Margin" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="SecondGrid.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="Green">


        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Grid x:Name="FirstGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="Yellow">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="500">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="500"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="lblName" />

            </Grid>

        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="SecondGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="500" Background="Blue">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="500"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Uid="lblAge" />

            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```